# How to read documents in RTF file type?

Tags: text-editor

I'm searching a way to maintain RTF files for open/editing but at least for reading, because I have no support for it on my device.

I tried mobile docs view and yozo office but they didn't support RTF.

Comment: I've edited your question to have it on-topic, since APP searching questions are considered off-topic. Refer to the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions) for further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read RTF files you basically just need and app that supports that file format.

Here's a good one that additionally supports many other document types:

[Cool Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.coolreader) by Vadim Lopatin available from Google Play Store.

> Reading books in epub, fb2, txt, doc, rtf, html, chm, tcr, pdb, pml formats.
>
> eBook reader. Supports epub (non-DRM), fb2, doc, txt, rtf, html, chm, tcr, pdb, prc, mobi (non-DRM), pml formats.

Comment: Good solution for **reading** rtf file

Comment: Cool Reader doesn't show up in the list of apps suggested to complete the action (of previewing the attachment).

Comment: @Michael Have you installed the APP from Google Play Store onto your device ?

Comment: @Michael No offence, just checking :) Have you restart the device, it may required that to update the list on available apps that support the file type!

Comment: restarting didn't make it show up.  i was able to get one of the other apps in this thread to appear as an option to open the attachment, although it didn't require a restart.

Answer (score 3):

- [ThinkFree Office Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tf.thinkdroid.amarket)
- [Android Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sibling.android.Office)
- [OfficeSuite PRO 6](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_registered)

All these claim to allow editing of RTF files.

Answer (score 1):

AndrOpenOffice is a good reader and has potential to develop into a good editor.

CloudOn may a good alternative but I haven't been able to try it yet.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, the best rtf Editor I have found sofar is OfficeSuite, which I use in conjunction with FolderSync, in case no WiFi is available, I can then edit the rtf on the lokal drive of the tablet and then sync with whatever cloud drive you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[Jota Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota&hl=es): a small program, not like the huge office suites.

I have tested it and **seems to be working**: I created a .rtf file from Jota on Android, sent to a Windows PC, and Wordpad opened it OK.

Issue detected: seems not to open (at least correctly) .rtf files created on Windows by using Wordpad (if someone knows how to correct it, please report). At least you can write your .rtf from scratch on your Android device.

Comment: Jota does not open files with RTF extension or from the suggested app menu for RTF.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Apabi reader for documents reading. This app is great for asia sepecific languages.